# Browsing OPCUA nodes only working on top level

Tags: java, client, opc-ua

I am using OPC UA project https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Java. I was able to browse all the nodes on an OPCUA Server using UAExpert.

Now I am trying to browse all nodes using my java client. I am able to retrieve references for the nodes in the first level of the node hierarchy where 
rootnameSpace = 1 and rootIdentifier = "simsre"

```
BrowseDescription browse = new BrowseDescription();
browse.setNodeId(new NodeId(rootnameSpace, rootIdentifier));
browse.setBrowseDirection(BrowseDirection.Forward);
browse.setIncludeSubtypes(true);
browse.setNodeClassMask(NodeClass.Object, NodeClass.Variable);
browse.setResultMask(BrowseResultMask.All );
BrowseResponse res = mySession.Browse(null, null, null, browse);
ReferenceDescription[] references = res.getResults()[0].getReferences();
```

When I call the code for other nodes like rootnameSpace = 31 and rootIdentifier = "/simsrede/"  beneath I still get a result but no references ( so res.getResults()[0].getReferences() returns null) 
-  The status code of the browseResponse is something like "GOOD" -

According to specification all unicode characters are allowed in the identifiers so slashes and '|' shouldn't be the problem.

I also tried adding entries into my namespacetable and using the table to set the node id in consecutive browse requests starting at the root node with

```
NamespaceTable table = NamespaceTable.getDefaultInstance();  
table.add(1, "urn:something:UnifiedAutomation:Uagateway"); 

...
//consecutive browse request starting from reference returned by first call
browse1.setNodeId(table.toNodeId(references[0].getNodeId()));
BrowseResponse res1 = mySession.Browse(null, null, null, browse);
ReferenceDescription[] references1 = res.getResults()[0].getReferences();
```

Anybody having an idea on why this is returning null references, or how to debug this ?

Comment: Are you sure this is this a valid NodeId? Can you browse the same node with other clients? Can you get a Wireshark capture?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was able to browse the nodes using UAExpert and the status code of the browseResponse is something like GOOD. I will trý get wireshark running in my environment - is it the best option to check the response ?

Comment: Compare a Wireshark capture from UaExpert to a capture from your code to see what you're doing differently/wrong.

Comment: Also FWIW that Java stack from the OPC foundation is no longer maintained. You might consider https://github.com/eclipse/milo instead.

Answer (score 1):

I used a Browse function

```
Byte[] cp;ReferenceDescriptionCollection refs; m_session.Browse(null, null, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder, 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out cp, out refs)
```

and i get if refs collection of the nodes from first level. Foreach node I called Browse function in recursion where I add nodes to the collection of OPCTreeNode

```
        public void GetChildNodes(Session sesja, ReferenceDescription Parametr, OPCTreeNode treeNode)
    {
        ReferenceDescriptionCollection nodes;
        byte[] tmpbytes;
        sesja.Browse(null, null, ExpandedNodeId.ToNodeId(Parametr.NodeId, sesja.NamespaceUris), 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out tmpbytes, out nodes);
        foreach (var tmpnode in nodes)
        {
            OPCTreeNode tmpNode = new OPCTreeNode($"{tmpnode.DisplayName}", $"{tmpnode.NodeId}");
            treeNode.ChildTreeNodes.Add(tmpNode);
            GetChildNodes(sesja, tmpnode, tmpNode);
        }
    }
```

OPCTreeNode class

```
    public class OPCTreeNode // element struktury parametrów sesji 
{
    public string DiplayName { get; set; }
    public string NodeId { get; set; }

    public List<OPCTreeNode> ChildTreeNodes;

    public OPCTreeNode()
    {
        ChildTreeNodes = new List<OPCTreeNode>();
    }

    public OPCTreeNode(string displayName, string nodeId)
    {
        this.DiplayName = displayName;
        this.NodeId = nodeId;
        ChildTreeNodes = new List<OPCTreeNode>(); 
    }
}
```